# Not gate in uppaal

Tags: properties, uppaal

I have model simple NOT gate in uppaal with propagational delay. But I am unable to prove one property. Screenshot of automata is attached. Xinp is input, xout is output. 3 is used as propagational delay here.

```
P1: A[] (xinp && t>3 imply (xout==!xinp))
```

This property is working correctly , after 3 time unit, output becomes negation of input.

```
P2: A[] (xinp && t<3 imply (xout==!xinp))
```

This property should be unsatisfiable so that I can verify that not gate is working after the propagational delay and before 3 time unit output is not according to not gate. BUT this property is not unsatisfiable.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Double negatives are confusing in English: what do you mean by "property is not unsatisfiable"? The property is either satisfied or it is not. In this case if A[] property is not satisfied, then there is a counterexample (and Uppaal should provide one). 
Does xinp change over time?

Comment: i mean property should be unsatisfiable, so that i can  verify Not gate is not working before 3 time unit i-e output is inverse of input only after the 3 time unit. Counter example showing error in s00 and outgoing edge. xinp is defined as a boolean and not changing over time.

Comment: as I understand your Uppaal counter example says that the property is indeed *not* satisfied (trivially) at s00. So I don't see any contradiction except ambiguous expression "not unsatisfiable" -- it must be either satisfied, or not satisfied.